# Wake on Lan utility for local only to sleep and wake up machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, wake-on-lan

I am looking for a Wake-on-Lan utility that works locally, not via the internet (so no setting up a router for WOL) to allow for waking up AND putting to sleep a machine.  I can't seem to find any.  I have machines that are running Windows 7 and XP Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Josip pointed out WOL can wake a computer up.

As for putting a computer to sleep you might look into.

VNC programs

Telnet

Back Orifice, Teamviewer, and other remote administration tools

Stoned Bookit

Not sure if any of these help but it is a start.

Answer (score 1):

Configure BIOS to use Wake-on-LAN.

`Configure the Network Adapter > Advanced TAB > enable Wake on Magic Packet`
Save changes.
Remember the IP address.
Hibernate or Sleep your PC.
Use the RD Connection tool(Start Run --> `mstsc.exe` ) on another PC with the IP to connect to your PC.
Done!

NOTE: sometimes the first connection fails, try it at least twice! This is mainly caused by a slow wake up on some PC's.

Do not use any 3rd party software, it is not needed, everything is standard from Windows 7 up.

Comment: Would you care to post a link and intro to this "RD Connection tool"?

Answer (score 0):

Wake on LAN protocol cannot put your machine to sleep. It is designed solely to wake machine up.

Programs that offer shutdown of remote machine usually do that through shutdown command (that does not support sleep).

Some program might have it's own custom client (that must be installed on each machine you wish to control) that can perform sleep action. However, i am not aware whether such program currently exists.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, Wake-on-LAN is not what you're looking for.

However I recently wrote a program that might help you. It can sleep and wake-up your PC according to configurable rules.

You can find more information about it here: http://ignatu.co.uk/SmartPower.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out WOL can not be used for putting the computer the sleep.

Regarding waking the computer up you first need to configure you computer to wake-on-lan. Note that you don't install special software that allows the computer to wake-on-lan but rather enable the option in you computer's network card (NIC), given that it supports WOL. This is normally done either through your BIOS settings or through some software tool (maybe included in the OS). I use the program `ethtool` on Linux to set the `g` flag for my NIC which tells the card to accept a so called "magic packet". The magic packet needs to contain that cards MAC address and is the signal that flips the "on" switch inside the NIC making the computer starts up.

Then you need an utility to send the magic packet. I use Depicus' [Wake On Lan Command Line tool](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-cmd.aspx) from my Windows machine.

I recommend Depicus' site and [WolCenter.com](http://www.wolcenter.com/) as excellent sources for WOL info.

(I know this is an old post, just putting the info here for other people's reference)

Answer (score 0):

Wake-on-LAN allows you only to power up remote PC, in case if it’s configured properly. But it can’t shut down PC remotely. Shut down is a task for another tool. If you need to make wake up and shut down you have two options:

First: use command-line tools for WOL and shutdown. Windows includes shutdown.exe utility. You can find a lot of free WOL command-line implementations.

Second: use commercial tool for power management. I can recommend [EMCO Remote Shutdown](http://www.emco.is/products/remote-shutdown/features.php). It has nice UI and can operate with multiple PCs to run WOL, shutdown, reboot and other tasks on schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I would install Teamviewer. It is a free remote control program that has the capabillity to WOL and you can remote in to shutdown or put the computer in sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

A simple easy answer is to just logoff as your power options will do the rest.

I have a pc upstairs I remotely use for testing etc I set my power options to 5 minutes sleep and then after 30 minutes it hibernates.

so putting it to sleep really is not that big an issue as you can set the power option to sleep in 1 minute if you like.

another way could be to remotely log in and just use the hibernation option from command prompt.

example: shutdown -h

There is even powershell to execute command remotely from another pc.

I have found though the best way is power management option with a low timeout and hibernation included as this saves even more power than just sleeping.

Hope that helps.